# iMacros: Specific drop-down menu

Tags: html, web, imacros

This is my drop-down menu:

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
    <select id="product-select" name="id" class="">
        <option value="1">White</option>
        <option value="2">Black</option>
        <option value="3">Grey</option>
```

and my solution didn't works:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:product-select ATTR=* CONTENT=$White
```

Can you guide me?

Comment: Does it matter that the select and div tags are not closed or is that just saving some chars? (I have no idea about imacros so I don't understand what is expected, perhaps clarify?)

Comment: I want to mark option White or Black or Grey.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=NAME:id CONTENT=%1